# What does `join` do in terms of equijoin in SQL or operations in relational algebra?

Tags: text-processing, join, coreutils, sql

`join` in coreutils reminds me of equijoin in SQL.

> `join` writes to standard output a line for each pair of input lines that have identical join fields.

I am not very clear about what `join` does from the coreutile's manual. Could you explain what `join` does in terms of equijoin in SQL or operations in relational algebra?

Which fields are required to have identical values?

What differences are between `join` and equijoin?

Thanks.

Comment: `man join` - "       join - join lines of two files on a common field"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `join` utility, by default, does what's called an "inner join" in SQL, resulting in the combined records of those entries whose join field is identical in both files. Yes, this is an "equi-join" since it's using equality for the test between the fields.

The `join` utility can do inner joins (default), as well as left, right and outer joins (using `-a1`, `-a2` and `-a1 -a2` respectively).  All these joins are "equi-joins" with `join` since equality is used for the comparison.

The join field is by default the first whitespace-separated field in each file, but this may be changed using the `-1` and `-2` command line options (for selecting the join field in the first and second file, respectively), and the delimiter may be changed to another single character using `-t`.

The default behaviour of `join` is similar to

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.firstfield = table2.firstfield);
```

except that you would only get one copy of the join field (`firstfield` here).